# Unite two dataframes by a MultiIndex

Tags: pandas

I've used a Python library (recordlinkage) who returned a Pandas MultiIndex like this:

```
df3
index  match
1/4     1
1/5     0
2/5     1
```

The first index is from df1 and the second is from df2.

I want to know how to united both dataframes now. I already remove the 0s match and I need this:

```
from_df1   from_df2
  name1       name4
  name2       name5
```

Where:

```
 df1:
 index  name
 1      name1
 2      name2
 3      name3

df2:
index  name
4      name4
5      name5
6      name6
```

Comment: It's a good first try to provide example data, but spend some more time to extend your information. For example add `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: ok, but where is df1 and df2?

Comment: df1 and df2 are two dataframes to be merged by the indexes of df3

Comment: what happens to index `3` in df1 and index `6` in df2?